# selenium + capybara: find selector anywhere within element

Tags: selenium, xpath, capybara

Assume we have a `<div class='whatever'>`  and somewhere deep inside there is an element `<div class='inside-whatever'>`

**What i need** is a way to access that particular *inside-whatever*-div  using Capybara's and/or Selenium's methods.

**Problem is**, there is another `<div class='inside-whatever'>` on the page **not** inside `<div class='whatever'>`, so

```
within(:xpath,'//div[@class="whatever"]') do
  find(:xpath,'//div[@class="inside-whatever"])
end
```

returns an error basically saying that there are multiple *inside-whatever* divs on the page.

**What works** is to build the xpath from *whatever* like

`'//div[@class="whatever"]/div/div[3]/div/div[5]'`

but that is pure madness.

So, is there any better way to look for selector **anywhere** inside any given element without having to specify a direct path?

Comment: Have you tried just merging them both? `//div[@class="whatever"]//div[@class="inside-whatever"]`. You can also apend `[1]` to only get 1st node if capybara requires one result.

Comment: Now, sir, this `//div[@class="whatever"]//div[@class="inside-whatever"]` actually does work indeed. Please feel free to post that as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can merge your xpaths like this:

```
//div[@class="whatever"]//div[@class="inside-whatever"]
```

Comment: This defeats the whole purpose of `within`

Answer (score 2):

The real issue here is that you've fallen into the XPath // trap

```
find(:xpath,'//div[@class="inside-whatever"])
```

searches globally rather than from the context node.  Instead you should get used to starting your XPaths with `.//` which will search from the current context node

```
within(:xpath,'.//div[@class="whatever"]') do
  find(:xpath,'.//div[@class="inside-whatever"])
end
```

and do what you expect.  This is mentioned in the Capybara README - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap

Note: CSS selectors don't have this issue and for most elements people are selecting read cleaner, which is why Capybara defaults to the :css selector

```
within('div.whatever') do
  find('div.inside-whatever")
end
```